# Iterators over a Linked List in a Game in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, linked-list

I am using OpenGl in android and they have a callback method called draw that gets called with out my control. (As fast as the device can handle if I am not mistaken) I have a list of "GameObjects" that have a .draw method and a .update method. I have two different threads that handle each of those. So, the question is, can I declare two different iterators in two different methods in two different threads that iterate over the same Linked List? If so, do I simply declare `ListIterator<GameObject> l = objets.listIterator()` each time I want a new iterator and it won't interfere with other iterators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple iterators for the same list. They do not interfere with each-other.

What you cannot do is modify the list while the iterators are still active (I mean, you can, but this will break the iterators, they will fail with an exception).

Answer (score 1):

This will work just fine, iterating over a single instance with multiple iterators is not a problem.

As long as you use a `SynchronizedList`, there is no reason why you cant modify the list. The `SynchronizedList` will block concurrent modification to the list and make it thread safe.

I would recommend using the Guava library if it is available to you, and use their `SynchronizedList` data structure, as well at their `Iterables.filter` and `Iterables.transform` methods together with `Predicates` and `Functions` to sort and transform the List.

More about the Guava library here:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html

For clarity:

While iterating over the list, you must synchronize on the list in a block, like so:

```
synchronized(list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
        while (i.hasNext()){
            foo(i.next());
        }
}
```

Comment: SynchronizedList does not avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions in the Iterators.

Comment: iteration would have to be done in a synchronized block, but this is in the javadoc for SynchronizedList. I will edit the post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Just make sure that during iteration you are not modifying the list.
If you intend to do so; please synchronize the iteration.

Comment: synchronize doesn't avoid `ConcurrentModificationException` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, you need to safeguard your other methods as well. But i assumed that if concurrent modification is possible then Matthew would have used synchronized list. But usually even if you use synchronized list we forget to lock/synchronize list during iteration. Iteration is also thread safe but can throw concurrent modification exception in absence of explicit lock.